# JBoss Cpu usage (%99) after changing thread pool size for asynchronous

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, threadpool

I have an application that makes simulation. At that time it makes many ejb requests. Also  I call asynchronous methods ( a different bean)  from a stateless bean that makes large data insertion. When I migrate my application to Jboss EAP 6.4 , my simulation time has increased. Normally a simulation takes 12 seconds. But now it takes 160 seconds. I tried to change my ejb thread pool for asynchronous messages.

This is what I did.

```
<session-bean>
    <stateless>
        <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
    </stateless>
    <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
    <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
</session-bean>
<mdb>
    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
</mdb>
<pools>
    <bean-instance-pools>
        <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
        <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
    </bean-instance-pools>
</pools>
<caches>
    <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
    <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
</caches>
<passivation-stores>
    <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
</passivation-stores>
<async thread-pool-name="default"/>
<timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
    <data-stores>
        <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
    </data-stores>
</timer-service>
<remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
<thread-pools>
    <thread-pool name="default">
        <max-threads count="**300**"/>
        <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
    </thread-pool>
```

Now simulation takes 12 seconds like as before. But Now I have another problem . CPU is %99  after simulation is completed. It takes maybe 30 seconds to release resources. If I start a new simulation , when CPU is %99 . I have some locks in the code. Server waits to call required ejb methods.

I did not get what is problem, I think I have only changed max thread number, So server should just create threads when it is necessary.

Can you help me ? I do not have this problem **in Jboss AS 6**.  Maybe I made some performance tuning in Jboss As6, but I can't remember.

**EDIT:** I think problem is related to number of objects. It is not related to thread size.  I kept thread size 300 and decreased number of objects to be inserted, Then cpu usage is normal . I have 400000 database insertion. May be this JPA  entities keeps CPU busy.

Comment: Could you check how many threads and sockets created? I think you create too many and your process is struggling to handle them at the same time. It's a concurrency issue.

Comment: How can I check it using Jconsole?

Comment: Well, I would just use your OS' process management utility. Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am on windows

Comment: I really don't know how to use Windows, sorry. Could you Google it?

Comment: Meanwhile, could you set a max_thread to a very low valeu and run your simulation?

Comment: As I told in issue, When I  set it to low value, it takes 160 seconds for completion. It is not acceptable for my application. In jboss as 6 , it takes 12 seconds

Comment: You actually didn't mention you lowered the max thread limit. Before giving an solution, I need to know whether the bootleneck is memory, cpu or networking. I know, you said cpu is on top, but that could be a symptom.

Comment: When I use it for first time, it uses default  values which is 10. So I tried